# Mongoose pre-update hook working but changes aren't reflected in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I feel like I'm missing something very simple but I cannot get the `contact.fullName` value to update. `contact.middleName` updates as expected.

The hook is triggered, and the changes made are reflected in the conlogs, but not in the DB. The `fullName` field refuses to update but no errors are thrown. Kinda feel like I'm losing my mind here

The Mongoose schema/model:

```
const Contact = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  middleName: { type: String, required: false },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  fullName: { type: String, required: false },
});

// When a Contact is created, we populate the `fullName` field using a pre-save
// hook, which is working as expected:

Contact.pre('save', function (next) {
  const contact = this;
  contact.fullName = `${contact.firstName || ''} ${contact.lastName || ''}`;
  
  return next();
});

// on update, we want to update the fullName field as well. This is broken:

Contact.pre(\(updateOne|update)\, function (next) {
  const contact = this;
  const update = contact._update['$set'];

  const newFullName = `${update['firstName'] || ''} ${update['lastName'] || ''}`;
  console.log(newFullName);

  contact.fullName = newFullName;

  console.log(contact.fullName);  // i can see the correctly updated value here!

  if (update['middleName']) contact.middleName = update['middleName'];

  console.log(contact.middleName);  // i can also see this one!
  
  return next();
});
```

If relevant, the function that calls the `updateOne` action:

```
module.exports.updateContact = (req, res, next) => {
  const { contact } = req.body;

  Contact.updateOne({ _id: contactId }, { $set: { ...contact } }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    return next(result);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are calling `Query#updateOne()`, not `Document#updateOne()` so it will trigger `pre('updateOne')` query middleware and `this` will refer to the query, not the document. In this case, you should modify your code to something like:

```
Contact.pre(\(updateOne|update)\, function (next) {
  const update = contact._update['$set'];

  const newFullName = `${update['firstName'] || ''} ${update['lastName'] || ''}`;

  this.set({ fullName: newFullName })

  return next();
});
```

More detail [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes).

Comment: I am importing the Contact model and calling `updateOne` on it, so I'm not 100% sure what you mean. The doc link you sent is identical to my implementation of the pre-update hook as well. Also, I want the Query inside my pre-update hook, so I can access the new values. But either way the `set` function worked, though I still do not understand why `middleName` is updated by assignment but `fullName` is not...

Comment: When `updateOne` called on document, it will trigger `pre('updateOne')` ***document*** middleware but when it' called on model or query, it will trigger `pre('updateOne')` ***query*** middleware. Please read the section ***Notes on findAndUpdate() and Query Middleware*** carefully then you can understand.

Comment: I totally understand what you're saying and what the docs say. I just don't understand how it pertains to this. Like I said, I *want* the query middleware so I can access the new values, and from what I can tell, I don't need the document middleware: I can still update the document from the hook by calling `updateOne` on the *model* for `middleName` value, right? So why can't I do it for `fullName` in the same function? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It's because `middleName` is already in `req.body`, `if (update['middleName']) contact.middleName = update['middleName']` change nothing in this case.